# C# export a list to excel file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list in controller that returns to view
I want to download that list as an excel file if clicked to "export excel button"
I found some libraries that converts to excel file but you have to specify a path I want it to read as bytes and send it to view
I don't know how to convert list to excel file in memory and also don't know how to send it from controller to view

Comment: hint: the abstract class `Stream` is the logical abstraction over files in .NET, whether as an  actual file on disk (`FileStream`) or in memory (`MemoryStream`). Good libraries would let you create an Excel file as a Stream and not just as a path to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleWebApp.Core/Controllers/HomeController.cs)' ExcelPackage class has methods `.GetAsByteArray()` and `.SaveAs(Stream stream)` overload.

Comment: epplus has commercial license I need a free one

Comment: @eomer use version 4, it,s LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast way to make generic function. Without using Epplus (which from ver. 5 is not free for commercial use, that includes all software, that you build in company, even for internal use).

Old query but maybe someone will use it.
It's based on [this ms thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/0dcb58a0-5193-4ab7-b2c6-2742dd9e1be8/openxmlwriter-performance-issue-while-writing-large-excel-file-35000-rows-and-100-cells)

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Reflection;

//Pass list to method, you could also create extention for list, but this works for me
public void SaveExcel<T>(List<T> SaveList)
        {
            try
            {
                //you can both create or open existing file, id rather first create it on desired path and fill it.
                //excample to create
                //SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)
                using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, true))
                {
                    document.CompressionOption = CompressionOption.SuperFast;
                    //if you create then you have to create workbook and sheet part
                    WorkbookPart  workbookpart = document.WorkbookPart;
                    WorksheetPart worksheetpart = workbookpart.WorksheetParts.First();

                    OpenXmlWriter writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetpart);
                    writer.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
                    writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

                    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                    //write headers
                    Row row = new Row();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                    {
                        row.Append(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(property.Name), DataType = CellValues.String });
                    }
                    writer.WriteElement(row);

                    //get all items in list and add them te excel
                    foreach (T item in SaveList)
                    {
                        row = new Row();

                        var values = new object[properties.Length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                        {
                            //inserting property values to datatable rows
                            values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(item, null);
                            
                            //just create a library, list, dictionary what grinds you gears to get DataType you need, 
                            string smalltype = properties[i].PropertyType.ExcelCellShortValues();
                            string largetype = properties[i].PropertyType.ExcelCellLongValues();

                            Cell cell = new Cell();
                            
                            #region[1st way to create]
                            cell.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("", smalltype, "", largetype));
                            
                            if(values[i]!=null)
                                cell.InlineString = new InlineString { Text = new Text { Text = values[i].ToString() } };
                            else
                                cell.InlineString = new InlineString { Text = new Text { Text = "" } };

                            row.Append(cell);
                            #end region
                            
                            #region[2nd way to fill data]
                            //if (values[i] != null)
                            //    row.Append(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(values[i].ToString()), DataType = celltype });
                            //else
                            //    row.Append(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(""), DataType = CellValues.String });
                            #end region

                        }
                        writer.WriteElement(row);
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.Close();
                    workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
                    document.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);    
            }
      
        }
```